# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php

```
$login = array('action'=>'getSession', 'user'=>'user', 'password' => 'password');
```

same for

```
$login = array('action'=>$getSession, 'user'=>$user, 'password' => $password);
```

I am simply creating an array and am getting a syntax error,

Comment: the error is the line before.

Comment: The error is the missing semi colon on the line before that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `;` on the line before the one you showed.

Comment: Don't encourage users to not search the site or even the dupe list when typing in the title.

Comment: Then close the question as Duplicate, not as Too Localized ;)

Comment: @Kolink Are you saying you wouldn't have answered if the close-vote was spent differently?

Comment: @alex_b Not very well, as the top two "Related" are the exact same issue, and I'm sure most of the others are too.